# Setting the time of datetime.now()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get the current datetime and set the time to `00:00:00`.

To do this, I call:

```
current_date = dt.datetime.now()
current_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
print(current_date)
```

The output is:

```
2017-08-20 10:43:56.3243245
```

That is not what I expect. However, if I do:

```
current_date = dt.datetime(dt.datetime.now().date().year,dt.datetime.now().date().month,dt.datetime.now().date().day,0,0,0)
```

Everything is as I expect and I get the result:

```
2017-08-20 00:00:00
```

Why is this? What is going on?? Why does `replace` not work?

Comment: It does work, but it *returns a new object* that you ignore; it's not a mutating operation. See the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace. You could also just use `date.today()` for the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) returns a new `datetime` instance, so you should do:

```
>>> current_date = dt.datetime.now()
>>> current_date = current_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
>>> print(current_date)
2017-08-20 00:00:00
```

You should also replace `microsecond=0` in order to make it exactly `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 0):

replace method always return a new  value after replacing  so you need to store that value.

## Remember it returns a new value after replacing

like in your case.
It returns a new datetime instance, so you should do:

```
current_date = dt.datetime.now()
current_date = current_date.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0)
print(current_date)
```